# Looking for a fantasy/fairytale-ish movie (80s/90s) - girl in a crash dreaming up a fantasy world

Tags: identify-this-movie, fantasy

I was born in 1982. When I was a kid, maybe around 1990, I saw a children's friendly fairytale-ish movie. I don't know when it was produced, but probably in the 1980s or 1990s. Maybe even late 1970s.

American production (I think). English-speaking.

I remember only some bits of it, but I'm quite certain of these things:

It starts out with a family going by car in wintertime (probably around Christmas), on a road in or close to a forest. The main character, a girl, is sitting in the back of the station wagon car. She's sitting on a sled of some sort. I think she has dark/black hair. Maybe around 12-14 years old.

Suddenly there's a bump or something on the road, and the back door of the car opens. The girl on the sled is thrown out and is within seconds hurtling through the snow-covered forest on the sled.

She hits a tree.

When she wakes up she is in a fairytale-like land.

I remember some bits of the land, like for instance someone living in a house that looks like a bowling ball(?). I remember them sticking their heads out of the holes.

I think the movie then has our main character experiencing a mish-mash of fairytale-like situations.

Then in the end of the movie she wakes up as it was all obviously a dream and the people/family come to her and help her.

I've gone through endless lists of non-animated fairytale-ish movies on the web, but for some reason this movie doesn't show up anywhere.

Maybe it was a dream I had?

Comment: What country was it from? What language? Can you describe the actors ?

Comment: Paulie: Thanks for the comment. I added some info based on your question. I think it's an American production. English-speaking. The girl is maybe 12-14 years old.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I cannot find out how she goes to Toyland in this movies (If she actually hits her head), but is it by any chance [Babes in Toyland (1986)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babes_in_Toyland_(1986_film))?

Its a movie about an 11 year-old girl (Drew Barrymore) who is transported into this fantasy world during Christmas Eve where she has to fight against Barnaby (the villain).

> Lisa Piper (Drew Barrymore), an eleven-year-old girl from Cincinnati, Ohio, takes care of her siblings and cooks for her family. She has no time for toys, and refuses to be treated as a child. **During a blizzard on Christmas Eve, Lisa is transported to Toyland**.

---

And in the end:

> Lisa is taken home by the Toymaster - who is revealed to be Santa Claus - in a sleigh with wooden reindeer. **They travel across the Milky Way until she wakes up at home, as though it had all been a dream**.

[image]

Comment: I did not know that there is a move (or an operetta) of that title, I only ever knew the band. Interesting.

Comment: @CarstenS I, on the other hand, found out about the band, after I found this movie. Haha...